# Get Data of Controller Return

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

My problem is this, I have a page where there is a button used to change the state of a table.
What is happening is that if the page is scrolled and I click the button that is below, it will update the status page and will rise. What I want is that when the state changed it remains the place where the button was clicked.

**OPEN SHADOW:**

```
 $(".table-change-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var div = this.rel;
        $.get($(this).attr("href"), function (result) {
            $("#" + div).html(result);
            $("#" + div).dialog({ width: 500, height: 200, modal: true });
        });
    });
```

**VIEW**:

```
<td class="table-comand">
        <a href="@Url.Action("AlterarSituacao", ViewBag.Routes)" title="Atualizar Situação"      class="table-change-link" id="situacao" rel="DivAtualizaSituacao"></a>
        <div id="DivAtualizaSituacao"></div>
    </td>
```

**CONTROLLER:**
this is a action of request

```
  public ActionResult AlterarSituacao(int page=1)
        {
            CreateRouteValuesForFilters();
            routes.Add("page", page);
            ViewBag.Routes = routes;

            ViewBag.IdSituacaoDocumentoLOV = new SelectList(this.repository.GetAllSituacao().ToList(), "IdSituacaoDocumento", "NomeSituacao");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AlterarSituacao(int IdSituacaoDocumento, int id, int page = 1)
        {
            CreateRouteValuesForFilters();
            routes.Add("page", page);
            ViewBag.Routes = routes;

            this.repository.AlteraSituacaoDocumento(id, IdSituacaoDocumento);
            this.repository.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("Index",routes);
        }
```

How make this?

Comment: isn't this a positioning issue ? make it absolute and use css to initiate its position

Comment: Doing some tests, would be the question of the return of the controller I was not managing to get the value to update the page.